# typealias is not able to use producing Cannot invoke initializer Error

Tags: swift

I have a typealias as follow:

```
typealias Member = (memberId: Int64?,fullName: String?,photoUrl: String?)
```

when I call this as follow

```
Member(memberid: 14, fullname: "Nifras", photourl: "Hello")
```

I got the error like this

> Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Member' with an argument list of
>   type '(memberid: Int64?, fullname: String?, photourl: String?)'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Member` is an alias for a tuple. You are trying to create an instance of a `Member` like calling an initializer for a class or struct.

You want:

```
let someVar: Member = (14, "Nifras", "Hello")
```

Or you can use `Member` as a type for a parameter or return type.

```
func someFunc(someParam: Member)
```

or

```
func someFunc() -> Member
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `Member(memberId: 14, fullName: "Nifras", photoUrl: "Hello")` syntax, you have to create `struct Member`:

```
struct Member {
    memberId: Int64?
    fullName: String?
    photoUrl: String?
}
```

You can read more about structures https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ClassesAndStructures.html